# Usage of realloc function

Tags: c

For the first time i enter a string size of 9, 
after when i did reallocation and tried to print the string 
it is printing whole string. How to resolve this.
And what happens to the memory after 
5 bytes..! is it deallocated automatically or no need of doing anything.
Since u guys told to add '\0' at 4th Location.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    char *ptr;
    char str[10];
    printf("enter a string:\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    ptr=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    strcpy(ptr,str);
    printf("entered string is: %s\n",ptr);
    ptr=(char *)realloc(ptr,5);
    strcat(ptr,"\0");//i just tried but not helping
    printf("new string is: %s\n",ptr);
    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Don’t cast the return value of `malloc` (or `realloc`) in C.

Comment: When you use `realloc()`, you should do it this way `(char *) realloc(ptr, sizeof(char)*5)`. As I know `strcat()` automatically add `'\0'` character at the end of new string, so you should try `strcat(ptr, "")` but in thins case I believe this wont work, instead of this you can simply use `ptr[4] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\0"` is equivalent to an empty string, so `strcat`ting it onto `ptr` won’t do anything.

Instead, set element `4` to a null byte:

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, 5);
ptr[4] = '\0';
```

If the string is longer than 4 characters, it’ll be truncated, and if not, it will have no effect, since the terminator is before it.

Also, use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` and [not plain `scanf("%s")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c) to avoid buffer overflows.

And take Cody Gray’s comment below into account, but really, you should just allocate `sizeof str` instead.

Comment: And the memory size passed to `realloc` should be calculated the same way it is for the initial call to `malloc`.

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't avoid buffer overflows on its own, as it sometimes does not null-terminate the output. `snprintf` is easier to use.

Comment: @CodyGray I prefer the `realloc` version .. using the extended spelling of `1` is tedious

Comment: You're right, it doesn't matter in this case. But I think it is better style. I don't want to have to think about whether `char` can ever be != 1. I think it increases readability and maintainability if all calls to memory allocation functions look basically the same. @matt

Answer (score 0):

@false's answer is absolutely correct, but he does not explain *why* the whole string is initially being printed.

The reason is because the call to `realloc` with a smaller size does not actually cause any initialization to happen, and in particular does not cause a write to the memory. Instead, it just tells the memory management system that the bytes after the 5th byte are now available for reuse.

If you do a whole bunch of `malloc` afterwards, you will probably eventually observe the end of the string being corrupted.

Comment: That is merely an implementation detail. `realloc` would be perfectly within its rights to fill the unused memory with 0s or 7s or whatever it wanted. You're right, though, this does explain the behavior the asker is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

in C,STRING mean an null-terminated arrays of characters (memory block)
for example, string "enter" will occupied 6 bytes of memory(include null-terminated)

```
char* ptr = "test"; //will AUTO-allocated 5 bytes to stored string "test\0"
```

`malloc,realloc,free` are memory manager, NOT string manipulator, in your first malloc

```
ptr=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

system will preserved 10 bytes for your code-purpose,after realloc

```
ptr=(char *)realloc(ptr,5);
```

the original data **MAY** still preserved when new size fitted int the pre-allocated location,but in this point, the last 5 bytes already return to system,strcat it could lead program crash,becase you are trying to access the memory **NOT** belong to your code,if just need shrink string or something else, use string function instead